# jQuery on click SlideUp/Down script

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the following script:

```
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    var isVisible = $(".slide-div").is(":visible");
    $(".slide-div:visible").stop().slideUp(400);

    if (!isVisible) {
        $(".slide-div").slideDown(400);
    }           
});
```

The script works well, now I am trying to expand the script with a click outside the slide-div. So when I click outside the div it also slides up. I tried it with the following function, but that doesn't work.

```
$(":not(.slide-div)").click(function () {
    if ($(".slide-div").is(":visible");) {
        $(".slide-div:visible").stop().slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

Comment: try `$("*:not(.slide-div)")...`

Comment: If you want it to work on every click, try this `$(document).on('click', '*:not(.slide-div)', function() { $(".block-cart:visible").stop().slideUp(400); });`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am not sure what is happening now. When I click on clickme label the div slides down, but immediately slides up again. Both answers are giving the same result.

Comment: That's because you `.clickme` is outside `.slide-div`, I assume. So both events are triggered.

Comment: Off topic: why don't you use [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body', function (e) {

    var clicked_slideDiv = $(e.target).closest('.slide-div').length > 0,
        isClickme = $(e.target).is('.clickme'),
        isVisible = $(".slide-div").is(":visible");

    if(isVisible && (isClickme || !clicked_slideDiv)) { 
        $(".slide-div").stop().slideUp(400);
    } else if (!isVisible && isClickme) {
        $(".slide-div").slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

You can switch `body` with any selektor you want to narrow the "*outside of the div*" down to.